# Google Place API: how to autocomplete API for custom search?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am new to Google Api....Can Anyone please provide me code for PLACE Autocomplete if I only want to have autocomplete search-results related to hospitals only such that in search bar,it should display only hospitals name and nothing else.

Here Is My Code.It's Just Showing City Names in Search Field. I want Hospital's Name To be Searched.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Hotel Search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      table {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      #map {
        width: 440px;
      }
      #listing {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 470px;
        overflow: auto;
        left: 442px;
        top: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      #findhotels {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 4px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
      }
      #locationField {
        position: absolute;
        width: 190px;
        height: 25px;
        left: 108px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
      }
      #controls {
        position: absolute;
        left: 300px;
        width: 140px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #country {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .placeIcon {
        width: 20px;
        height: 34px;
        margin: 4px;
      }
      .hotelIcon {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
      }
      #resultsTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 240px;
      }
      #rating {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
      }
      .iw_table_row {
        height: 18px;
      }
      .iw_attribute_name {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
      }
      .iw_table_icon {
        text-align: right;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="findhotels">
      Find hotels in:
    </div>

    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a city" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="controls">
      <select id="country">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="au">Australia</option>
        <option value="br">Brazil</option>
        <option value="ca">Canada</option>
        <option value="fr">France</option>
        <option value="de">Germany</option>
        <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
        <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="it">Italy</option>
        <option value="za">South Africa</option>
        <option value="es">Spain</option>
        <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
        <option value="us" selected>U.S.A.</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <div id="listing">
      <table id="resultsTable">
        <tbody id="results"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div style="display: none">
      <div id="info-content">
        <table>
          <tr id="iw-url-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td id="iw-icon" class="iw_table_icon"></td>
            <td id="iw-url"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-address-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td>
            <td id="iw-address"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-phone-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Telephone:</td>
            <td id="iw-phone"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-rating-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Rating:</td>
            <td id="iw-rating"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-website-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Website:</td>
            <td id="iw-website"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // This example uses the autocomplete feature of the Google Places API.
      // It allows the user to find all hotels in a given place, within a given
      // country. It then displays markers for all the hotels returned,
      // with on-click details for each hotel.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var map, places, infoWindow;
      var markers = [];
      var autocomplete;
      var countryRestrict = {'country': 'us'};
      var MARKER_PATH = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/marker_green';
      var hostnameRegexp = new RegExp('^https?://.+?/');

      var countries = {
        'au': {
          center: {lat: -25.3, lng: 133.8},
          zoom: 4
        },
        'br': {
          center: {lat: -14.2, lng: -51.9},
          zoom: 3
        },
        'ca': {
          center: {lat: 62, lng: -110.0},
          zoom: 3
        },
        'fr': {
          center: {lat: 46.2, lng: 2.2},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'de': {
          center: {lat: 51.2, lng: 10.4},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'mx': {
          center: {lat: 23.6, lng: -102.5},
          zoom: 4
        },
        'nz': {
          center: {lat: -40.9, lng: 174.9},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'it': {
          center: {lat: 41.9, lng: 12.6},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'za': {
          center: {lat: -30.6, lng: 22.9},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'es': {
          center: {lat: 40.5, lng: -3.7},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'pt': {
          center: {lat: 39.4, lng: -8.2},
          zoom: 6
        },
        'us': {
          center: {lat: 37.1, lng: -95.7},
          zoom: 3
        },
        'uk': {
          center: {lat: 54.8, lng: -4.6},
          zoom: 5
        }
      };

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: countries['us'].zoom,
          center: countries['us'].center,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          panControl: false,
          zoomControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false
        });

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: document.getElementById('info-content')
        });

        // Create the autocomplete object and associate it with the UI input control.
        // Restrict the search to the default country, and to place type "cities".
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (
                document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
              types: ['(cities)'],
              componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
            });
        places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);

        // Add a DOM event listener to react when the user selects a country.
        document.getElementById('country').addEventListener(
            'change', setAutocompleteCountry);
      }

      // When the user selects a city, get the place details for the city and
      // zoom the map in on the city.
      function onPlaceChanged() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry) {
          map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(15);
          search();
        } else {
          document.getElementById('autocomplete').placeholder = 'Enter a city';
        }
      }

      // Search for hotels in the selected city, within the viewport of the map.
      function search() {
        var search = {
          bounds: map.getBounds(),
          types: ['lodging']
        };

        places.nearbySearch(search, function(results, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            clearResults();
            clearMarkers();
            // Create a marker for each hotel found, and
            // assign a letter of the alphabetic to each marker icon.
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26));
              var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';
              // Use marker animation to drop the icons incrementally on the map.
              markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[i].geometry.location,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: markerIcon
              });
              // If the user clicks a hotel marker, show the details of that hotel
              // in an info window.
              markers[i].placeResult = results[i];
              google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', showInfoWindow);
              setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
              addResult(results[i], i);
            }
          }
        });
      }

      function clearMarkers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          if (markers[i]) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
          }
        }
        markers = [];
      }

      // Set the country restriction based on user input.
      // Also center and zoom the map on the given country.
      function setAutocompleteCountry() {
        var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
        if (country == 'all') {
          autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': []});
          map.setCenter({lat: 15, lng: 0});
          map.setZoom(2);
        } else {
          autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': country});
          map.setCenter(countries[country].center);
          map.setZoom(countries[country].zoom);
        }
        clearResults();
        clearMarkers();
      }

      function dropMarker(i) {
        return function() {
          markers[i].setMap(map);
        };
      }

      function addResult(result, i) {
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26));
        var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 === 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
        tr.onclick = function() {
          google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
        };

        var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
        var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
        var icon = document.createElement('img');
        icon.src = markerIcon;
        icon.setAttribute('class', 'placeIcon');
        icon.setAttribute('className', 'placeIcon');
        var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
        iconTd.appendChild(icon);
        nameTd.appendChild(name);
        tr.appendChild(iconTd);
        tr.appendChild(nameTd);
        results.appendChild(tr);
      }

      function clearResults() {
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        while (results.childNodes[0]) {
          results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
        }
      }

      // Get the place details for a hotel. Show the information in an info window,
      // anchored on the marker for the hotel that the user selected.
      function showInfoWindow() {
        var marker = this;
        places.getDetails({placeId: marker.placeResult.place_id},
            function(place, status) {
              if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                return;
              }
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              buildIWContent(place);
            });
      }

      // Load the place information into the HTML elements used by the info window.
      function buildIWContent(place) {
        document.getElementById('iw-icon').innerHTML = '<img class="hotelIcon" ' +
            'src="' + place.icon + '"/>';
        document.getElementById('iw-url').innerHTML = '<b><a href="' + place.url +
            '">' + place.name + '</a></b>';
        document.getElementById('iw-address').textContent = place.vicinity;

        if (place.formatted_phone_number) {
          document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('iw-phone').textContent =
              place.formatted_phone_number;
        } else {
          document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Assign a five-star rating to the hotel, using a black star ('&#10029;')
        // to indicate the rating the hotel has earned, and a white star ('&#10025;')
        // for the rating points not achieved.
        if (place.rating) {
          var ratingHtml = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (place.rating < (i + 0.5)) {
              ratingHtml += '&#10025;';
            } else {
              ratingHtml += '&#10029;';
            }
          document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('iw-rating').innerHTML = ratingHtml;
          }
        } else {
          document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = 'none';
        }

        // The regexp isolates the first part of the URL (domain plus subdomain)
        // to give a short URL for displaying in the info window.
        if (place.website) {
          var fullUrl = place.website;
          var website = hostnameRegexp.exec(place.website);
          if (website === null) {
            website = 'http://' + place.website + '/';
            fullUrl = website;
          }
          document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('iw-website').textContent = website;
        } else {
          document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My_Api_Key&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello ! Welcome on StackOverflow. But I think you're at the wrong place to ask this kind of questions. We don't like to "provide code"; we prefer to fix already existing one with problems inside. Can you show us at least what you did as search, and why it is not working (and so why you need help because what you searched and find was not ok) ? Thanks ;)

Comment: Oops!!.Please see it@NatNgs

Comment: for specific city, see my answer here, hope it helps: stackoverflow.com/a/62294304/4324194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Search Function, in variable search change types field to hospital like:

```
var search = {
      bounds: map.getBounds(),
      types: ['hospital']
    };
```

and in the Autocomplete predictions so far only "country" restriction is supported as stated in the documentation:

"componentRestrictions can be used to restrict results to specific groups. Currently, you can use componentRestrictions to filter by up to 5 countries. Countries must be passed as as a two-character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code. Multiple countries must be passed as a list of country codes."

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

If you would like to add this feature for Autocomplete, there is already a case in the issue tracker where you can add your vote to support this request in:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820774

Comment: It displays Hospitals in Map,but I want to Search Hospital  Only By it's name in Search box instead of City.......How to Do that.

Comment: I am afraid you can not, even if you subtitude the options in the search (where you have ('cities') ) for hospitals It won't work...is just not supported for Autocomplete

Comment: there is already a Feature request for this for a while (2011) but looks like is not gonna be supported https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820774 , you can add your vote to support this request

Comment: Anytime, here to help

Answer (score 1):

To be very clear for rookies like me (because I wasted a lot of time on this) you **cannot set an Autocomplete request to return specific types of places.**

For example, if you want Autocomplete to return just hospitals, or just restaurants, or just parks, as of April 2022, you can't.

This issue requesting that ability was opened in 2011 and hasn't been handled yet. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820774

You can only set Autocomplete to return classes of places, by setting the type to something in Table 3 here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types

Table 3 options are:

1. geocode
2. address
3. establishment
4. regions
5. cities